# Better practice: Ever looping thread or successive threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Currently, my application is making calls to REST APIs periodically, and I'm using one dedicated thread to do that (request() is an object's method):

```
void MyObject::request() {
    while (m_continue) {
        //API call, printing response, then sleeping 30 secs
        usleep(30*1000);
    }
}
```

And making a thread like:

```
thread t(&MyObject::request, this);
t.detach();
```

**But using c++11 or Boost, is it a better practice to use an ever looping thread than multiple successive threads/async functions ?**

Like this:

```
string MyObject::request() {
    //API call, printing response
}
```

And calling it multiple times like the following, using the future result and calling request() asynchronously each time:

```
while (m_continue) {
    future<string> f = async(request);
    cout << f.get() << endl;
    usleep(30*1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use "an ever looping thread". You would have a considerable overhead because of `std::async`. You would be creating a new thread all the time you call `std::async`.

So it's better to create one only once and then call your API periodically.

the "`<future>`" classes, functions, etc, like `std::async`, have awesome interfaces for paralellization of tasks, but behind the scenes they uses kernel threads (just like `std::thread` does), it means `pthreads` or windows threads or whatever the platform offers. So they are not very useful for something that happens periodically, once you would be creating threads all the time and it has a considerable cost.

Here is a very nice video from CppCon 2014 with deep details and benchmarks:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xyztU__yys

--

By the way, nothing to with your question, but why not use `this_thread::sleep_for()` ? :-)

```
void MyObject::request() {
    while (m_continue) {
        //API call, printing response, then sleeping 30 secs
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(30));
    }
}
```

Comment: `sleep_until` with a monotonic clock might be a better choice for this. Less drift on that 30 seconds.

Comment: as desired! :-)

Comment: Is it necessarily the case that `std::async` spawns a new thread every time? The underlying implementation could use a thread pool, for example.

Comment: yes @Rook, it could. The problem is exactly this. They don't. Just like the video explain... the interface is generic and it means "let's parallelize this thing"... however the way it's done is via kernel threads. I am not sure if the standard limit this way or if it's just matter of implementation. the video proposes other implementations for the same interface because of this exact problem ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and that video was really helpful!